# Kernel version in uname differs from version in rpm

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

In CentOS - the output of **rpm -qa | grep -i kernel**  shows one version (**3.10**.XX) :

```
kernel-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
```

However the output of **uname -mrs** shows different version (**4.18**.XX)

```
Linux 4.18.16-x86_64-linode118 x86_64
```

does this make any sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a feature provided by your cloud hosting provider, Linode. They have a document named [How to Change your Linode's Kernel](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/how-to-change-your-linodes-kernel/) that contains the following information:

> Your Linode is capable of running one of three kinds of kernels:
>
> - An upstream kernel that is maintained and provided by your Linux    distribution’s authors (this is also referred to as the
>     distribution-supplied kernel).
> - The Linode kernel. **Linode maintains an up-to-date kernel: Linode’s engineering team monitors for new versions of the Linux kernel and then packages them for users shortly after they are available. These kernels are not installed on your filesystem–instead, the Linode Manager supplies them at boot time to your system.**
> - A kernel that you compile from source.

That explains why the installed kernel package is different from the running kernel, as reported by `uname`.

The same document also contains the following about the choice of kernel:

> Most distributions that can be deployed from the Linode Manager boot
>   the upstream kernel by default. **CentOS 6**, OpenSUSE Leap 42.3,
>   Slackware, and Ubuntu 14.04, and older distributions are exceptions to
>   this rule, and they boot the Linode kernel by default.

For your own system, you can verify this by following the instructions in the document I have linked to. Briefly, the configuration should be visible at Settings > Advanced Configurations > [Current Configuration] > Edit > Boot Settings > Kernel.